# VirtualQueryEx how do i parse the results (how do i know if the page is readable or not by ReadProcessMemory?)

Tags: winapi

I am trying to learn how to access other process's memory. I'm using `ReadProcessMemory` but it fails, supposedly because i'm reading from an unaccessible memory. I think I should use `VirtualQueryEx` first to find out if the memory I'm trying to read is readable, but I don't know how to parse the results of `VirtualQueryEx`.

`VirtualQueryEx` returns a structure described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Is there any good simple way to know whether the values in the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure  tell that the page is readable by `ReadProcessMemory` or not?

This structure has several parameters that, from what I understand, define whether or not memory is accessible:

```
DWORD  AllocationProtect;
DWORD  State;
DWORD  Protect;
DWORD  Type;
```

Its not even clear on what combination of parameters actually allows reading the memory (for example, should I read Protection flag from `AllocationProtect` or `Protect`, does `State` other than Commit mean that memory is unreadable, etc) and making a huge if (this is that and that is that or this is that....) doesn't seem like a clean solution.

There's got to be a better way, but I don't seem to be able to find it...

Comment: Generally speaking, you shouldn't be using `ReadProcessMemory` for IPC in the first place. Consider an alternate way of transferring data between processes.

Comment: I need to hack a program to do something it cannot do in the first place. Specifically, I'm adding new hotkeys to a game.

Comment: It's not clear how `VirtualQueryEx` helps you in that quest. But at any rate, since `ReadProcessMemory` fails when it can't read the memory, that's your answer right there. No need to ask `VirtualQueryEx` "Can you read the memory?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the clue is in the documentation you linked:

> **AllocationProtect**
>
> The memory protection option *when the region was initially allocated*. This member can be one
>   of the memory protection constants or 0 if the caller does not have access.

`VirtualProtect` or `VirtualProtectEx` could have been used meanwhile to change the protection (per-page, while the initial protection was for the whole allocated range). So you'd have to check the `Protect` member of the structure against the [Memory Protection Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the MSDN documentation that state that read is allowed. Checking for a single bit doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: In other words, is it correct to check for State == 0x1000 and Protect being one of PAGE_EXECUTE_READ PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY PAGE_READONLY PAGE_READWRITE PAGE_WRITECOPY